# ValueError:: low >= high

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to resolve ===
Help me to fix this

```
plt.figure(1 , figsize = (15 , 9))
n = 0 
for i in range(49):
    n += 1 
    r = np.random.randint(0 , cells.shape[0] , 1)
    plt.subplot(7 , 7 , n)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.5 , wspace = 0.5)
    plt.imshow(cells[r[0]])
    plt.title('{} : {}'.format('Infected' if labels[r[0]] == 1 else 'Unifected' ,
                               labels[r[0]]) )
    plt.xticks([]) , plt.yticks([])
    
plt.show()
```

In line =
r = np.random.randint(0 , cells.shape[0] , 1)
there is error = ValueError:: low >= high

Comment: What's in `cells`? Which line gives the error?

Comment: is `cells.shape[0] == 0`?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `np.random.randint(low=0, high=cells.shape[0], size=1)`.

The error indicates that `low >= high` which suggests `cells.shape[0] == 0`.
`np.random.randint` picks a number in the range `[low,high)` so there are no possible numbers to pick, which causes the error.

To debug this check `print(cells.shape)` and even `print(cells)` to ensure the values in `cells` are what you expect.

You could also add a check before the `for` loop:

`if cells.shape[0] > 0:`